# Failed to lookup view in views directory by express.js and path

Tags: node.js, express, path

I have a problem to route views by node.js and express.js
The tree of my project is look like :

```
app/
   app.js
   views/
       index.html
       login.html
   public/
         css/
         js/
```

I use express and path ; Here is my code to set paths:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
//forms
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//public 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "login.html" in views directory "/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/app/views"
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:966:7)
    at /home/Project/V0.0.8_3/app/routes/login.js:11:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/xvps/Tracker/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/Project/V0.0.8_3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

and when I try to get a file from public directory I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /js/login.js
```

Actually I know different between local path and server path and I have read a lot of related questions have been asked in **stack overflow** but I cannot find what is my mistake.

**UPDATE**

And the routing code is here:

var router = express.Router();
require('./router')(app);

the router.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var login  = require('./routes/login');

module.exports = function (app) {

    /* Index(main) route */
    app.use('/', routes);
  app.use('/index', routes);
  app.use('/index.html', routes);
  app.use('/login', login);
  app.use('/login.html', login);
  app.use('/logout', logout);
};
```

at routes directory there are two js files; index.js and login.js

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
  // fetch all users
  .get(function (req, res) {
    console.log('get method');
    if(req.session.logged) {
      res.render('index.html');
    }
    else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }

  });    
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can you post also your routing code ?

Comment: @sand I have just updated question and added route code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was beginner on coding by node.js and uploading on server I was running my code on server by *`npm`*, one of my friends helped me t find my problem. I must run the app by **`pm2`** to get a live application.

Answer (score 1):

Which express version are  you using?

### Updated

In express 4 middlewares are built in external modules, so for static files in you case, you should use serve-static middleware:

Example code:

```
var express = require('express') 
var path = require('path') 
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var app = express()       
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))) 
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: the express version is 4.15.2

Comment: (For the js in public file) In express 4 the express.static builtin was replaced by a middleware. Here you have the entire list of equivalent middlewares:
http ://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware.html

Comment: I don't understand your mean :(

Comment: The problem still exist! In public/js there is login.js file; When I 'exit' from server, requesting to this file shows me 'Cannot GET /js/login.js'

Comment: What do you mean with 'exit' the server?

Comment: I log on server by `ssh user@ip` and log out by `exit` I am using VPS server by command line; And recently I've found the `home` folder is encrypted and this caused the error, but I don't know how remove encryption from this folder

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error, but after getting some mental fatigue I am able to resolve this. Here is the solution that works fine for me.
Change this line of code `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` to `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));` this.